# Notation for dimension of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Is it an unusual notation to write $|V|$ for the dimension of a vector space $V$?
Is it ok to use it if you blur the distinction between the grid for the finite element method and its associated function space?

Comment: this is certainly not a standard notation. ${\rm }(dim)(V)$ is more common. It's ok to use that notation if you make sure it is clear. I don't quite understand the rest of your question.

Comment: I meant ${\rm dim}(V)$

Comment: $\dim(V)$ or $\dim_F(V)$ if you want to specify the field as well.

Comment: The notation $\lvert V \rvert$ is particularly confusing if you are dealing with a *finite* vector space, where it would definitely refer to its cardinality.

Comment: I would think it more confusing for an infinite-dimensional vector space, where the cardinality may not simply be that of the underlying field.

Comment: I believe I have seen the notation $|V|$ used in some linear algebra books.